# Proving that if $f=0$ on an arc or region in $D$, where $f$ is analytic on $D$, than $f = 0$ on $D$.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, complex-integration, analytic-functions

In the book of *The Theory of Functions* by Titchmarsh, at page 88, it is first stated that

> Let $f(z)$ be a function analytic in a region $D$, and let $P_1, P_2,
> > ...$ be a set of posts having a limit-point $P$ inside $D$. Then if
>   $f(z)=0$ at every point $P_n$, it follows that $f(z) = 0$ at all
>   points of $D$.

Than, as a corollary it is given the following without a proof,

> If a function is analytic in a region, and vanishes at all points of
>   any smaller region included in the given region, or along any arc of a
>   continuous curve in the region, then it must vanish identically.

I want to show that if $f$ is analytic on $D$, and $\exists E \subseteq D$ (E is a region) s.t $f|_E=0$, then $f = 0$ on $D$.

Proof:

We can express $f$ as 
$$f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_n (z-a)^n \quad \forall z \in D.$$
for some $a\in E$.

Then since we can find a sequence of point $P_i$ in $E$ that converges to $a$. Since $f(P_i) = 0$, by the previous theorem, $f = 0$ on $D$.

Note that, even $E$ was just an arc in $D$, we could still approach to a zero of $f$ with a sequence of points all of which are zero of $f$, hence by the previous theorem, $f=0$  on $D$.

---

I'm new to the subject, so I would really appreciate if you could point the mistakes in the proof, or tell me whether is it valid or not.